# WD-40 pronunciation question treated badly

Tags: discussion, specific-question, pronunciation

We had a [potentially interesting question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/586413/why-the-pronunciation-of-wd-40-is-double-d-forty-and-not-double-u-d-forty) based on pronunciation of a common house-hold chemical....

The question  was quickly shoved off without much ado to the closed questions queue and closed..
It was actually an interesting question, just badly put.

In the particular post, a comment was made by a well-respected user: "It's not clear to me what research Tomás should have done that he didn't do."

We need to start polishing good ideas, not discourage new users.
There are still some of us that look for the germ of an idea, a kernel of interesting data that will expand our knowledge.

The question is apparently based on regional pronunciation, or more probably, socioeconomic.*

I would like to see that post re-opened.

---

{EDIT}

the post was re-opened, and then re-closed.

Please vote to re-re-open.
We need more questions of this type that draw interest and traffic to the site...

*Look at the number of comments and good answers.

Comment: Why do we need more questions of this type? And, btw, exactly what **is** "this type"?

Comment: @JohnLawler I am talking about questions concerning regional accent...also, please notice how much traffic this has drawn to the site, and how many users are interested. That's two types.

Comment: The OP never said it was a common household product for oiling mechanical parts. I cannot stand it when OPs put up questions and do not identify them. In fact, there is regional pronunciation AND the FACT that for the BUSH name everyone says Dubbya, regardless of where they live. :)

Comment: @Lambie I don't wanna sound like a mansplainer, but most guys that oil their machine parts and knives would be aware of this product...for manly men, we all know WD-40....(I think my cousin and daughter use it for sewing machines)...but is universal for simple lubricant  needs of machine parts.

Comment: Well, dearie, I know what it is, too. But there are participants who aren't American and would not know it. :) In other words, it's a product not a "term". :)

Comment: It's regional, that's what makes it interesting. It includes pronunciation of products going back like 80 years  And don't call me dearie. If anything I am quite unbearably bearish..

Comment: It's likely not regional. If it has any specific associations, socioeconomic speech groups are more likely than areal groups. I.e, you shouldn't be asking **Where?**", you should be asking Who?, with special details on race, status, and income level. Sociolinguistic variation rarely refers to areas, but rather to independent speech group habits.

Comment: @JohnLawler Sorry, but I just can't picture, as a general proposition,  any real Texan with a Texas drawl not saying dubbya, even if highly educated. Similarly, I don't think anyone in the Boston area goes around saying dubbya, unless referring to George W. as Dubbya.

Comment: That's why there are sociolinguistic surveys, so we don't hafta depend on what we can imagine. Turns out the distribution of features like this is more temporal and contextual than anything else. I.e, somebody in group A might use it an average of 40% of the time, but those in group B use it 65% of the time. And there's a lot of groups.

Comment: @Lambie (all these content comments should probably be over at the question on main)... IPA is not catching all the nuance... the Texan version is very much 'duh-byuh', the Boston (or rather the GenAmE version is closer to 'duh buh yuh' with the middle one very short, not Texan but enough to tell that there might be a difference.

Comment: @Mitch You don't get what I am saying: **The president's nickname is pronounced the same everywhere**. **Dubya**. Even by Bostonians when they say it. That's the whole point of it.

Comment: @Lambie oh I'm sorry I missed that. I was talking about the letter in general.  Currently in the Boston area, 'dub yuh' for the former president isn't a universal (and I think not -that- common there)

Comment: @Mitch No, you are wrong., "Dubya" is a nickname precisely because of the Texas drawl for the letter. As such, everyone pronounces it the same way. Geesus. /"WHAT DOES DUBYA MEAN?
Dubya is a nickname for the 43rd president of the United States (2001–2009), George W. Bush. It’s based on that middle initial, W., used to differentiate him from his equally presidential father of the same name.".https://www.dictionary.com/e/politics/dubya///What is the matter with everyone about this??

Comment: The pronunciation information is on the Wikipedia page for the [letter W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W), under "Name". That should be a fairly obvious place to do research. I think there are many worse cases of failure to do research in a question, but claims that "there's no way to research this" are plainly incorrect.

Comment: How was that Question not purely dependant on one speaker's pronunciation or worse, one listener's hearing? Doesn't that suggest any Answer will always be a matter of opinion? A site with a mechanism for producing "pure" pronunciation might be helpful, but how would that "pure" be defined?

Comment: NB: What WD-40 is *not* is a lubricant. It is never meant to be used that way. What it is is a "penetrating oil," and what it does is loosen metal things (e.g., screws and nuts and bolts) that have become frozen stuck.

Answer (score 7):

It's been reopened and the title has also now been edited to remove the obvious misconception from generalising the particular (which probably contributed to closure).

Comment: Though it now has a close vote again. (Maybe the [title needs to be changed more](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/586413/why-do-some-pronounce-wd-40-double-d-forty-and-not-double-u-d-forty#comment1468490_586413)?)

Comment: @Laurel If you think it needs to be changed again, go for it. However, the suggestion you link to supposes that everyone misses the third syllable of W, which isn't the case.

Comment: Yeah I think that not assuming a universal pronunciation is good, but it might be necessary to remove the misconception from the title (since it's "doubya" not "double").

Comment: But that misconception is crucial to the question. The OP there is definitely discerning "double D forty" instead of "double-U-D-Forty", possibly because he's unaware of *dubya*, which is the answer to the question (as indeed has been given).

Comment: It looks like OP edited the title along the lines I was thinking anyway.

Comment: The OP also assumed that the phonological variation was geographical, which is unlikely, but insists on getting an areal name. When it would take a language survey to begin to answer the question. I bet it could be done for under a million in the US.

Comment: @JohnLawler Even if it is a socioeconomic issue, and not regional, how does it make it off-topic on EL&U? C'mon, this is our bread and butter.

Answer (score 1):

It should remain closed. I (British English - Yes, they sell it here and in the rest of Europe) have listened to the linked Youtube video and nowhere do I hear anything but "double-you-dee-forty". The question was asked on the basis of a mishearing by a Spanish speaker who admits the mishearing might be his fault. EL&U cannot explain why the mishearing took place, nor does it need to: the question does not need an answer as it does not exist.

Comment: I am from New York, and still pronounce it "dubya dee fordy"...that is the way I always heard it.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine - close enough.